# Service References are appearing as folders

Tags: service, reference

I have been having this problem with Visual Studio 2012(2010).  My service references are being turned into folders when run project in Expression Blen.Also when this happen,  I can't see "update service references" in popup menu when right click on service name.
Please see this [web page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9aeb8f3b-85e8-4fca-8da0-d32fd25caf9b/sevice-references-are-appearing-as-folders).

Comment: I saw that happen once. I have no idea why. If you are using source control, compare your current project file to a known good one. Otherwise, just delete the service reference and add it again.

Comment: Clean up your .config file.

Comment: Thanks.I don't have source control,also When I delete service reference and add it again,I get this error: An endpoint configuration section for contract could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.Although,to Prevent this error, it is needed to delete other endpoint address with similar contract name in ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file.But repeat this action is boring.